# Mobile Application HTTPS traffic capture : Unable to browse apps (appear as offline) when traffic is routed via JMeter proxy

Tags: android, jmeter, ssl-certificate, network-traffic, traffic-simulation

Trying to capture application traffic generated by Mobile apps like YouTube/Facebook by routing the traffic through JMeter. JMeter Certificate is installed on Android. Still unable browse applications (shows as offline).

In JMeter logs, following errors appear: 
1. Problem with ssl certificate for url for 'x.y.com'. Ensure browser is set to accept the JMeter proxy cert. Received fatal alert: certificate unknown

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [http-canary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.guoshi.httpcanary&hl=en_US) for Android.
It captures traffic from installed apps, you could use it on your own rooted device or on an emulated one with [Bluestack](https://www.bluestacks.com/).

You could also use Wireshark or Charlesproxy with another device in the middle.